# ¿Cómo integrar font awesome en workflow usando webpack?

Tags: css, npm, sass, font-awesome, laravel-mix

Estoy trabajando una pequeña página en la cual utilizo un workflow, y ahora necesito integrar Font Awesome pero no está funcionando como debería, cuando ejecuto el comando **npm run watch** en consola, no se compilan los estilos que tenía en mi archivo de sass (estoy usando sass), unicamente está el código de fontawesome y por lo tanto mi página se muestra sin ningún estilo...
No se que pasa en realidad.

En mi workflow estoy intentando agregarlo de esta forma:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.pug = require('laravel-mix-pug');

mix.setPublicPath('dist');

mix.js('src/js/script.js', 'dist/assets/js/')
.sass('src/scss/style.scss', 'dist/assets/css/')
.pug('src/views/*.pug', '../../dist/', { pug: { pretty: true } });

//====AQUI INTENTO AGREGAR FONT AWESOME====
 mix.styles([
   'src/libs/all.min.css'
 ], 'dist/assets/css/style.css');

 mix.scripts([
   'src/js/jquery.min.js',
   'src/js/script.js'
 ], 'dist/assets/js/script.js');


 mix.browserSync({proxy: false, files: ['src/**/*'], server: {baseDir: 
'dist/'}}); // browser-sync
mix.copyDirectory('src/img/', 'dist/assets/img');
mix.copyDirectory('src/fonts/', 'dist/assets/fonts');
```